# Render subfolder url from different top level folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, smf-forum

I'm not very good on LAMP environment, but I need to accomplish the following and was hoping for some direction.

I have a Wordpress site that maps to a folder structure like such:

/firsttoplevelfolder/MyWordpressSite

I have a SMF forum that maps to a folder structure like such:

/secondtoplevelfolder/MyForumSite

The forum is currently delivered at a url like: 
http://www.example.com/forum

The Wordpress site is currently delivered at a url like: http://www2.example.com

I would like the Wordpress site delivered at a url like (www --> www2):
http://www.example.com so that it is the root domain
So that the forum sites under the same top level domain as the wordpress site.

This would result in the following:

http://www.example.com - Wordpress site

http://www.example.com/forum - SMF site

How do I accomplish this since they are in subfolders under different top level folders?

Edited to add that I'm using 1&1 shared hosting, if that changes things.

Comment: That is more a Vhost configuration. You need to access your apache config and change it.

Comment: you need to edit DocumentRoot of a domain or subdomain configuration under Apache Virtual Host

Comment: Is this doable in a shared hosting environment? These are hosted with 1&1.